# Able to update an API documentation automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I'm working on a web site which provides API for external developers.

Whenever the API is updated (i.e. modified parameters, new end points, etc), I have to update the documentation manually.

So I'm looking at how this process can be be done automatically. Here is what I hope to acheive: once my source code is updated and committed to my source control, some sort of an API Registry will be updated. So my documentation can be an app which refers to the registry and shows the viewers with the latest API.

My site is based on Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

RDoc is automatically generated based on your source code, and it comes default with Rails. Your code needs to be well-documented, but if it is, you can just run

```
bundle exec rake doc:app
```

and your app will generate documentation accessible from `doc/app/index.html`. I would look at that and see if such documentation fits your needs. Links in the "Class and Module Index" sidebar contain lists of all of your methods with expandable views of the source code for them.

I use a custom rake task that places all of that documentation in the Rails public folder for access directly from my website and allows me to add more than one custom page. I imagine it wouldn't be that hard for you to do something similar that only parsed your API files.

Links:

[RDoc Syntax Help](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/)

[Project on Github](http://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/)